# Getting a Following error while implementing Custom Membership Provider in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: claims-based-auth, membership-provider

Implementing custom membership provider in SharePoint 2010 I am getting the following error.

I am getting this error in the following page:
`http://home:55555/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx`

I copy the membership code in 3 `web.config` file.
1. My Current Web Application.
2. Central administration.
3. Security Token Web service.

```
<membership defaultProvider="i">
      <providers>
        <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
        <add name="CustomFBAMembership" type="CustomMemberShipProvider.Class.CustomMemberShip,CustomMemberShipProvider,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99f33d5f328d7f5a"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="c" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
        <add name="CustomFBARole" type="CustomMemberShipProvider.Class.CustomRoleBase, CustomMemberShipProvider,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99f33d5f328d7f5a"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

> Error
>
> Exception of type
>   'System.ArgumentException' was thrown.
>   Parameter name: encodedValue
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft
>   SharePoint Foundation.

FYI : When I am comment out the all `membership` and `rolemanager` tags from the Central Administration site `web.config` then it's working fine. I think the problem is somewhere in the membership provider tags.

Please help me out this problem.
Thanks

Comment: If you think your tags are the issue. Then try adding them using IIS.

Comment: Hi did you ever resolve this issue? I am struggling with kind of the same error. Sander

Comment: I am getting the same problem. Did anyone resolve that ?? Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the 3 web config will need to be configured differently eg

This for your FBA Site

```
<membership defaultProvider="i">
  <providers>
    <add name="i" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthMembershipProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="CustomFBAMembership" type="CustomMemberShipProvider.Class.CustomMemberShip,CustomMemberShipProvider,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99f33d5f328d7f5a"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="c" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
  <providers>
    <add name="c" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.Claims.SPClaimsAuthRoleProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="CustomFBARole" type="CustomMemberShipProvider.Class.CustomRoleBase, CustomMemberShipProvider,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99f33d5f328d7f5a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

This for the token and central admin

```
    <membership defaultProvider="i">
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomFBAMembership" type="CustomMemberShipProvider.Class.CustomMemberShip,CustomMemberShipProvider,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99f33d5f328d7f5a"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager>
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomFBARole" type="CustomMemberShipProvider.Class.CustomRoleBase, CustomMemberShipProvider,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99f33d5f328d7f5a"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your code. It is likely in issue with your custom membership provider, since it works when you remove it from the web.config. When it is added to the web.config your membership provider is initialised. Also check the ULS log for a stack trace, which likely will pin down your problem.

Comment: can you please provide me some good links so i can Implement the Custom Membership provider on my site.

Comment: when I remove the role Provider from my Central Administration Site. Then I try to check the custom provider. It works for me. But my question is this why RoleProvider not working in SharePoint 2010?